# ReactJS update simple array onChange of inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I have the following property with social icons:

```
items: {
    type: 'array',
    default: [
      { icon: 'twitter', url: '#' },
      { icon: 'facebook-square', url: '#' },
      { icon: 'youtube', url: '#' },
    ],
 },
```

I have some controls:

```
<InspectorControls>
    <PanelBody title={ __( 'Social Network Settings' ) } initialOpen={ true }>

    {items.map( ( item, index ) => (

        <Fragment>

          <SelectControl
            label="Social Network"
            value={ item.icon }
            options={ [
                { label: __( 'Twitter' ), value: 'twitter' },
                { label: __( 'Facebook' ), value: 'facebook-square' },
                { label: __( 'Instagram' ), value: 'instagram' },
                { label: __( 'YouTube' ), value: 'youtube' },
            ] }
            onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { items: [ ...items, { icon: value } ] } ) }
          />

          <TextControl
            label={ __( 'Social Link' ) }
            value={ item.url }
            onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { items: [ ...items, { url: value } ] } ) }
           />

        </Fragment>

    ) ) }

    </PanelBody>
</InspectorControls>
```

And I'm rendering social icons:

```
{items.map( ( item, index ) => (
  <a key={ index }
     href={ item.url || '#' }
     target="_blank"
  >
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', item.icon]} />
  </a>
) ) }
```

3 icons are showing. The correct icon name is showing in each select control. However when I change the icon in the select control, a new icon is added, instead of updating. The same goes when adding URLs, blank  tags are being added.

How can I update the array when changing the select and text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` logic above implies that a new item will be added on each update.

Your `onChange`should find the correct element and update it accordingly. 
As example the `onChange` for`Social Network` would look something similar to below. You should implement similar logic for the other onChange too.

```
onChange={( value ) => {
  const newItem = {...item, icon: value };
  const newItems = [...items];
  newItems[index] = newItem;
  setAttributes({ items: newItems });
}}
```

Comment: Very cool! Thank you! That works. And to remove items I could just use this? `const newItem = {...item, icon: '', url: '' };` That seems to remove the values but not the item ass well from the array.

Comment: Or this seems to work but not sure if correct: `const array = [...items];
     array.splice(index, 1);
      setAttributes({ items: array });`

Comment: Hello Panther! I have one more question if you don;t mind... would it be correct to also use `const newItems = [...items];
           newItems[index].icon = value;
           setAttributes({ items: newItems });` ? The code seems a little shorter.